# simplexml_load_file() PHP function not working to load xml from given api url

Tags: php, api

when i type the following url in the browser, it works.

http://beermapping.com/webservice/loccity/api_key/lyons,co

but the following php code does not work.

```
$beerdata = simplexml_load_file ("http://beermapping.com/webservice/loccity/api_key/lyons,co");
print_r($beerdata);
```

I have confirmed that in my php.ini file both the attributes `allow_url_fopen` and `allow_url_include` are  set to `on`.

Comment: Perhaps the beermapping site is blocking requests that don't come from a web brwser

Comment: What do you mean by "code does not work"? Do you get any error? If i click on your link, i get an empty page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$xml_file = "http://beermapping.com/webservice/loccity/api_key/lyons,co";
$lines_array = file($xml_file);
$lines_string = implode('', $lines_array);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($lines_string);
print_r($xml);
```